# Google Maps API overlaycomplete only recognizing first drawing

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map that allows the user to draw a circle or polygon around the markers they would like to select. It is working in as much as they can draw the shape, hit the select markers button, and select those markers. I have a clear map button that when they click deletes the drawn shape.

Where it breaks is if they want to draw an additional shape. Anything drawn after the first is not being picked up by the event listener (as none of the console logs are firing off). The shape draws, but since it's not picked up by the listener, clearing them off the map doesn't work nor using them to select different or additional markers.

Here is an example of my code:

```
    var map;
    var marker;
    let markers = [];
    let selectedMarkers = []
    let all_overlays = [];
    var addresses = {{CLAIMS-JSON||[]}};
    const mapElement = document.getElementById("map");

    function initMap() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(30.6954, -88.0399);
    // The map, centered at Uluru
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: latlng,
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    //create drawingManager so users can draw on the map
    const drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER, //top center drawing menu
            drawingModes: [
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.CIRCLE,  //allow circle or polygon only
                google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
            ],
        },
        circleOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1,
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            strokeWeight: 5,
            clickable: false,
            editable: true,
            zIndex: 1,
        }
    });

    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    let markerCluster = new markerClusterer.MarkerClusterer({markers, map});
    let markersArray = [];
    addresses.forEach(address => {
        let claimLat = address.lat;
        let claimLng = address.long;
        let claimLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(claimLat, claimLng);


        map.setCenter(claimLocation);

        var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: '<b>' + address.id + '</b>',
            size: new google.maps.Size(150, 50)
        });
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: claimLocation,
            map: map,
            title: String(`${address.id}: ${address.address}`),
        });
        marker.set("id", address.id);
        markersArray.push(marker);
        markerCluster.addMarker(marker);

    })
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {
        let paths = []
        for (var i=0; i < all_overlays.length; i++)
        {
            console.log("clearing all overlays:" + all_overlays[i]);
            all_overlays[i].overlay.setMap(null);
        }
        all_overlays = [];
        if(event.type == 'circle') {
            all_overlays.push(event);
        console.log(all_overlays);
            const center = event.overlay.getCenter();
            const radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
            let markerLat;
            let markerLng;
            markersArray.forEach((mark) => {
                markerLat = mark.getPosition().lat();
                markerLng = mark.getPosition().lng();
                markerLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat, markerLng);
                let checkDistance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(center, markerLoc);
                if(checkDistance <= radius){
                    selectedMarkers.push(mark.id);
                }
            })
        }else if (event.type == 'polygon'){
            all_overlays.push(event);
        console.log(all_overlays);
            paths = event.overlay.getPath();
            let polygon = new google.maps.Polygon({paths: paths});

            markersArray.forEach((mark) => {
                markerLat = mark.getPosition().lat();
                markerLng = mark.getPosition().lng();
                markerLoc = new google.maps.LatLng(markerLat, markerLng);
                let isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(markerLoc, polygon);
                if(isWithinPolygon){
                    selectedMarkers.push(mark.id);
                }
            })
        }
        $('#map-select-claims-button').show();
    });

    }

    window.initMap = initMap;

    //the button to clear the map
    $('.clearMap').on('click', function() {
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(all_overlays.length)
    for (var i=0; i < all_overlays.length; i++)
    {
        console.log("clearing all overlays:" + all_overlays[i]);
        all_overlays[i].overlay.setMap(null);
    }
    all_overlays = [];
    })
```

I've tried having the push to all_overlays inside the if statements and at the top of the event listener below the "let paths = []" but it all results in the same behavior. The first overlay is recognized, and I can clear it. Others are not.

Comment: Not valid: `var addresses = {{CLAIMS-JSON||[]}};`.  Is `MarkerClusterer` needed to demonstrate your issue?  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the issue, preferably a working [StackSnippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) in the question itself, including any required HTML/CSS and data.

Comment: Perhaps the issue is the **addListenerOnce**:  `google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete',` (but can't run the code to tell).

Comment: Change `addListernerOnce` to `addListener` and I believe it will work as you expect.

Comment: Thanks @geocodezip that resolved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

typo.

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {...}
```

should be:

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {...}
```